# resizing c++ vector size for less-than-contiguous arrays?

Tags: c++, vector

Say we have various int values to map to pointers to data.  We know they're not going to be so sparse that we want a `map<>` and we like the fast lookup of a `vector<>`.

I'm a seasoned C guy (and C++ albeit not with STL) but it doesn't seem right that the code should be something as verbose as:

```
if (i>= vec.size())
    vec.resize(i+1);

if (!vec[i])
    vec[i] = pmydata;
```

Further, has the least-verbose way of doing this changed over the various C++ editions?

Comment: "Doesn't seem right?" What's that supposed to mean? This *is* the way to do what you want.

Comment: And it's not verbose enough - you probably need a cast on `i` or `size()` to eliminate a signed/unsigned comparison warning.

Comment: You can use a wrapper / adapter around vector so it provides the map-like interface you like.

Comment: There's no intrinsic way of making a vector 'grow' to accommodate anything other than a one-after-the-last element. (use `push_back()` of `emplace_back()`). If that's what you mean.

Comment: To those who wonder what "Doesn't seem right" mean. Try and think how a newcomer at c++ sees the language. If you don't know a language very well, it's legitimate to think you are not using it properly

Comment: You're a seasoned C programmer and you think that's verbose?

Comment: You're complaining about verbosity of this?   If you were doing something equivalent in C, I'll bet you pennies to donuts that your code would be more verbose.   For example, you might use `realloc()` to do the resizing, but you would need to check that it succeeds - in itself that will take more lines of code than you have shown.

Comment: > You're a seasoned C programmer and you think that's verbose?  Yep.  In C for 25 years I'd be calling a function like ArySetIfUnset().  In C we still have functions and libraries of course; any project with more than about one dynamic array would have a tiny library to keep the higher-level code from having to call realloc()... or a resize() method...

Answer (score 2):

The stl does not provide a shortcut for this kind of container. The way you emulate it is the right one.

As mentioned by Marc Glisse, you could write an adapter over std::vector to provide the same interface as std::unordered_map or std::map.

Although c++ provides some great containers, you still have to implement some things by hand to suit your precise needs.

Comment: You can even write a free function: `void extend(vector<T>& vec, int index, T value)`. Just *don't* do what they did at my current job and derive a new class from `std::vector` replacing the `operator[]` method, it just makes it impossible to reason about.